# How can I turn on my computer and immediately execute my program using C#?

Tags: c#

well i am developing a simple program (for me) it is for a note notes, you put a day and a time to your note, when it was the time and day, it appears a ballontip,
i have a problem here to, any time i put to this ballontip, it ever get to be only 5 seconds

```
DateTime hora; // hora == time
DataTable tabla = daonota.seleccionaraahora();  //chose now =seleccionar ahora 
if (tabla.Rows.Count == 1)
{

    hora = Convert.ToDateTime( tabla.Rows[0][4].ToString());
    string titulo = tabla.Rows[0][1].ToString();  
    String texto = tabla.Rows[0][2].ToString();  
    texto=texto+"\Date programmed="+tabla.Rows[0][3].ToString(); 
    texto = texto + "\nTime programmed=" + tabla.Rows[0][4].ToString();
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(10000, titulo, texto, ToolTipIcon.Info);

}
```

i have this code in a timer (timer1) it do a query every secund, do you know any form better for to do it (goal is it appears a ballon tip in the time put)

well i want to to ... if the computer is turn off, it turn on, any code for to do it since c#? and another thing... how do i do, my program is execute since the computer turn on, automatically?

Comment: .NET applications are managed applications, and can't get as close to the hardware as you'd hope they can. There's no way to get a .NET program to run until the OS is done starting itself up, so you can't get it to run the moment a computer starts up. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I've translated some of your Spanish text to English, for clarity for those who don't speak the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a link to your program in the registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Then it will run every time the computer starts.

Comment: mmm but i dont want to do it, manuality, then how do i do my program, do it, the first time was executed? or how do i do it, when it is installing? (i've never used c# for installation)

Comment: @angel It depends on how the user will use your application - if they run it, or the computer runs it.  It sounded like the computer runs it, so you'd want to put the link in via the installer.

Comment: @angel You should ask a new question on how to set this registry setting via the installer.

Comment: @angel if you want to do it by your program I can help you with that.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I understood the whole question but still a few points:

- You may want to look at the *Windows Service* type application. It will start before a User logs in.
- "I [..] do a query every secund"  : That's too fast for the balloon stuff. The noftification has it's own Timing and Queuing rules.

Answer (score 3):

Well it's limited

> [Minimum and maximum timeout values are enforced by the operating system and are typically 10 and 30 seconds, respectively, however this can vary depending on the operating system. Timeout values that are too large or too small are adjusted to the appropriate minimum or maximum value. In addition, if the user does not appear to be using the computer (no keyboard or mouse events are occurring) then the system does not count this time towards the timeout.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160064.aspx)

Other limitations, background info: http://www.csharp411.com/notifyiconshowballoontip-issues/

1. Timeout Limits
2. Requires User Activity
3. One Balloon at a Time
4. Balloon Never Closes

Tip: To Close Balloons

To explicitly close a balloon at any time, simply set the NotifyIcon.Visible property to false, then immediately back to true.

Answer (score 1):

Add your program to your startup folder.

Comment: i dont want to do it manuallity, how do i do my program do it for itself?

Answer (score 1):

Your program need to be a Process. Search for "C# Process"